# Problema de árboles binarios con recursividad en javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy teniendo problemas para resolver este ejercicio que me pasaron con recursividad.
Se supone que debo determinar la profundidad de un arbol binario creado previamente. Al determinar el primer nivel no encuentro ningún problema, ahora, se pierde la precisión al adentrarme en niveles más profundos y no puedo encontrar el porque.

```
// Implementar la función height dentro del prototype de BinarySearchTree que debe devolver la "altura"
// máxima del arbol recibido por parámetro.
// Ejemplo:
//             16             ---> Nivel 1
//          /      \
//        6         23        ---> Nivel 2
//      /  \       /   \
//     2    14    17    31    ---> Nivel 3
//      \
//       5                    ---> Nivel 4
// Este arbol tiene una altura de 4
// PISTA: Una forma de resolverlo es pensarlo recursivamente y usando Math.max

BinarySearchTree.prototype.height = function() {
  // Tu código aca:
  var accR = 0;
  var accL = 0;
  if(!this.right && !this.left) return 1;
  if(!this.right && this.left)  return accL++ + this.left.height();
  if(this.right && !this.left)  return accR++ + this.right.height();
  if(this.right && this.left) return Math.max(accR++, accL++) + this.left.height() + this.right.height();
}
```

Comment: Intenta con `return Math.max(accR++ + this.left.height(), accL++ + this.right.height());`

Comment: Hola Alan, la corrección que proponés ya la intenté sin éxito antes de llegar al código posteado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que se puede simplificar la lógica con solo una condicional y un par de asignaciones ternarias para calcular la altura de cada extremo y enviando la altura del elemento actual para evitar cálculos innecesarios.

```
// Implementar la función height dentro del prototype de BinarySearchTree que debe devolver la "altura"
// máxima del arbol recibido por parámetro.
// Ejemplo:
//             16             ---> Nivel 1
//          /      \
//        6         23        ---> Nivel 2
//      /  \       /   \
//     2    14    17    31    ---> Nivel 3
//      \
//       5                    ---> Nivel 4
// Este arbol tiene una altura de 4
// PISTA: Una forma de resolverlo es pensarlo recursivamente y usando Math.max

BinarySearchTree.prototype.height = function(height = 1) {
    if(!this.right && !this.left) {
        // No hay elementos, devolver profudidad actual
        return height;
    } else {
        // Calcular profundidad máxima en cada extremo con asignación ternaria
        // Si el extremo no tiene elementos, se mantiene profundidad actual
        let lHeight = (!this.left) ? height : this.left.height(height + 1);
        let rHeight = (!this.right) ? height : this.right.height(height + 1);
        // Se devuelve el mayor de ambos extremos
        height = Math.max(lHeight, rHeight);
    }
    return height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución bastante simple sería la siguiente:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.height = function() {
    let lh = !this.left ? 0 : this.left.height();
    let rh = !this.right ? 0 : this.right.height();
    return 1 + Math.max(lh, rh);
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente, muchos más sencilla.